# Am I setting the log4j home System Variable(for Classpath) correctly?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm having alot of trouble setting up log4J on windows. I am reading the [online how-to](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/build.html) but it's not really clicking:

So this is how I set my System Variable:

[image]

The full var.  value is :

```
C:\apache-log4j-2.0-beta4-bin\org\apache\logging\log4j\core
```

And then I add the LOG4J_HOME variable tothe PATH variable.

But I still get errors when compiling. Does anybody have pointers on this?
Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, you have unzipped the apache-log4j-2.0-beta4-bin.zip to C:\ drive.
This gives you a whole bunch of jar files in that directory.
**You don't need to unzip these jar files.**

Instead, when you compile your java program, you add some of these jar files to the classpath.
You probably only need to add

1. log4j-api-2.0-beta4.jar
2. log4j-core-2.0-beta4.jar

These two jar files are usually enough. The other jar files are helpers for special cases. Some cannot be used together, so don't just add all of them!

The details of how to add these jar files to the classpath when compiling depends on what you are using to compile.

By the way, log4j 2.0 beta5 was released recently with some new features and lots of bugfixes.

Comment: Hi Remko , So then would I afterwards only need to add the import line `import log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar;` to get it working?  thanks.!

Comment: Hi Adel, can I guess that you are new to java? That is great, best of luck, and don't give up if it is hard to figure things out immediately!  Back to your question: in your java code you would probably write `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;` and `import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`.  These are classes contained in the log4j-api-2.0-beta4.jar and log4j-core-2.0-beta4.jar.  If you get compile errors you need to add these jars to the classpath.  (classpath is different from the windows PATH env variable) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Thank You Very Much !  I got it to work now! (drJava  has an option for "extra classpath")

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you probably have to add string ";C:\apache-log4j-2.0-beta4-bin\org\apache\logging\log4j\core" to the tail of windows's system variable 'CLASS_PATH'. If you can't found 'CLASS_PATH' in your system variables list, then you have to add it. After this, log out your windows account and log in. It should work.

Comment: Hmm, I did set it up like that though